# Filter results between two custom number fields

Tags: search, low-search

I have two custom fields. One is a start year and one is an end year. I need to filter my search results based on if the search query falls between that range. I have read the docs related to the range:field_name filter but can't seem to wrap my head around what I need to do?

e.g. If someone types 1998 into the year custom field, it MUST find an entry where the year falls between the custom_field_1 and custom_field_2 values.

I tried this as the field name but it errored out with the Disallowed Key Character message.

```
<input type="text" name="range:vehicleYearFrom|vehicleYearTo" id="years" placeholder="Year">
```

I hope this makes sense. :-)

Thanks for your help!

---

**UPDATE:** Everything works except when I try to combine the range and the search filters I get no results. If I use ONLY field search filters it works fine, and if I use ONLY the range filter, it works fine, but when I use both, I get no results. Any ideas why?

```
  {exp:low_search:form
    force_protocol="https"
    result_page="/get-started/%s"
  }
    {error_message}
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-12 large-8 large-centered columns">
        <div id="your_vehicle">
          <h2>Your Vehicle</h2>
          <p><i>e.g. 2003 Buick Rendezvous</i></p>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 large-4 columns">
              <input type="text" name="range-from:vehicleYearFrom" id="yearsFrom" placeholder="Year">
              <input type="text" name="range-to:vehicleYearTo" id="yearsTo">
            </div>
            <div class="small-12 large-4 columns">
              <input type="text" name="search:vehicleMake" id="makes" placeholder="Make">
            </div>
            <div class="small-12 large-4 columns">
              <input type="text" name="search:vehicleModel" id="models" placeholder="Model">
            </div>
          </div>
          <br>
          <h5><a href="{path='money-back-warranty'}">100% Money Back Guarantee</a> - Free Shipping on Purchases of $30 or More</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
  {/exp:low_search:form}
```

Comment: I'll need to take a look myself. Please send SuperAdmin login credentials to hi at gotolow dot com if you can.

Comment: Also, how in the world can you keep the search values in their respective fields after an error is thrown due to a missing required field or something? As is, it clears everything out so if you miss one field, you've got to start from scratch. Hmm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having two channel fields for the range means you also need two input fields to filter. The `name` attribute of an input field always takes a *single parameter*. You're actually looking at *two* different ranges. To clarify:

- You have to fields; a `FromYear` field and `ToYear` field.
- You have one value you want to match against, so 2 ranges.
- For the first range you would want all matches where `FromYear` goes *up to* your number.
- For the second range, you would want all matches where `ToYear` *starts at* your number and up.

In an example, the Buick has `FromYear` 2002 and `ToYear` 2007. Enter year 2003.

- `FromYear` should be <= 2003.
- `ToYear` should be >= 2003.

In LS ranges, targeting these fields: `range:FromYear="|2003" range:ToYear="2003|"`, or in the different syntax: `range-to:FromYear="2003" range-from:ToYear="2003"`.

Changing that to input fields you can use in your form, you'd probably need something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="range-to:FromYear" class="year-range">
<input type="hidden" name="range-from:ToYear" class="year-range">
<input type="text" id="year" placeholder="Year">
```

And then use JavaScript to change the values of the `year-range` hidden input fields on form submit, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Low. The more and more I was thinking about it, the more and more I thought exactly what you were saying.

I did think about just having the from field replicate to the to field instead of having all 3 fields. That should work too, right?

Comment: Indeed it would, yes.

Comment: Thanks again! Can always count on your for excellent support! :-)